typescript discriminated unions not working in normal code but working in tsx react element
for some reason in the below code, "rest.selected" doesn't work, I get that selected doesn't exist in the type. but it works fine with Tsx react elements props.
and is there a way to make selected not accessible in react components props, when linkType is not set, as by default it's "normal" ??
import { cva, type VariantProps } from "class-variance-authority";
import NextLink from "next/link";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

const link = cva("", {
  variants: {
    linkType: {
      normal:
        "text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:text-black",
      tabLink: "border-b-2 px-0.5 py-3",
    },
    selected: {
      true: "",
      false: "",
    },
  },
  compoundVariants: [
    {
      linkType: "tabLink",
      selected: true,
      className: "border-black",
    },
    {
      linkType: "tabLink",
      selected: false,
      className:
        "border-transparent text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:text-black",
    },
  ],
  defaultVariants: {
    linkType: "normal",
    selected: false,
  },
});

type LinkPropsVariant = VariantProps<typeof link>;

export interface LinkProps
  extends React.LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
    LinkPropsVariant {}

type LinkTypeProps =
  | ({
      linkType?: "normal";
    } & Omit<LinkProps, "selected">)
  | ({
      linkType: "tabLink";
    } & LinkProps);

export const Link = ({
  linkType = "normal",
  children,
  className,
  ...rest
}: LinkTypeProps) => {
  const _link =
    linkType === "normal"
      ? link({ linkType: linkType })
      : link({ linkType: linkType, selected: rest.selected });

  if (linkType === "tabLink") {
    console.log(rest.selected === true);
  }

  return (
    <NextLink href="#" className={cn(_link, className)} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </NextLink>
  );
};

